# cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Media.Brush' to 'System.Windows.Media.Color

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to get a colour selector working inside my combo box iv managed to get it to list the colours but I'm having some issues getting it to convert from `Media.Brush` to `Media.Color`.

```
private void BrushColorCombo_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Color DrawColor = (Color)(BrushColorCombo.SelectedItem as PropertyInfo).GetValue(null, null);
}
```

---

```
startPoint = e.GetPosition(PaintCanvas);

rect = new Rectangle
{
    Stroke = Drawcolor,
    StrokeThickness = 1
};

rect.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Drawcolor);
Canvas.SetLeft(rect, startPoint.X);
Canvas.SetTop(rect, startPoint.Y);
PaintCanvas.Children.Add(rect);
return;
```

Comment: Which line is the problem? The error seems pretty obvious, what exactly is confusing you?

Comment: The errors at ` rect.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Drawcolor);` just telling me it cannot be converted iv tried looking it up and changing code but no luck (Errors at "Drawcolor")

Comment: Obviously, `Drawcolor` is a Brush. You've assigned it to the Rectangle's Stroke before, so `rect.Fill = Drawcolor;` should also work.

Comment: This seems to prevent me from drawing only way i can get it to work is with `rect.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);` but that then stops me selecting colour

Comment: It's unclear what your actual question or problem is. However, that you can't pass a Brush as constructor parameter of a  SolidColorBrush should be pretty clear.

Comment: Yes, I understand that I have an alternative way but its a lot messier than using something like this. it involves a lot of if statements which is something I really didn't want

Comment: Well, `rect.Fill = Drawcolor;` just works. No idea why you would need the new SolidColorBrush at all.

Comment: Well whenever i try that i can no longer draw on my canvas

Comment: Iv uploaded it to [GitHub](https://github.com/AndrewTibbles/PaintProject/tree/master/Paint_W_Canvas) so you can see what I mean.